# Why do we need the oneliner Dockerfile with just a FROM command inside the Spring-boot source code folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am learning how to dockerize Springboot applications using docker-compose command, a docker-compose.yml, and a dockerfile.

I am able to run the following example and understand how the docker-compose command work.
There is one thing I still don't understand, which is the one liner dockerfile inside the app folder. If you open the dockerfile, there is literally just a FROM command specifying the docker image.
Of course, the pom.xml is included in the app folder. That's what you need to compile a springboot application. And there is a command "mvn clean spring-boot:run". That is what triggers the compile process of the spring-boot code. But why can't we move the FROM command to the docker-compose.yml file? Is it not supported?

https://github.com/hellokoding/hellokoding-courses/tree/master/docker-examples/dockercompose-springboot-mysql-nginx

I am able to run the following example and understand how the docker-compose command work.
There is one thing I still don't understand, which is the one liner dockerfile inside the app folder. If you open the dockerfile, there is literally just a FROM command specifying the docker image.

https://github.com/hellokoding/hellokoding-courses/tree/master/docker-examples/dockercompose-springboot-mysql-nginx

Comment: Hey and welcome to Stack Overflow, can you please add the content of the files to the post, so that users can look at it later (after you removed the repository for example). Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You are right that, in this case, it does not make any sense and the following change to the docker-compose file should still work:

```yaml
  app:
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    expose:
      - "8080"
    command: mvn clean spring-boot:run
    depends_on:
      - hk-mysql
```

to

```
  app:
    restart: always
    image: FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    expose:
      - "8080"
    command: mvn clean spring-boot:run
    depends_on:
      - hk-mysql
```

In a compose file you don't use `from`, you use `image` to refer to an existing (or pull-able) image.

I think that the code you are referring to is like this, to be extended later. I noticed that it's part of an online course, that's why I expect more logic will be added to the Dockerfile later.